VBA Search Bar on Protect Sheet
I created a spreadsheet with a search bar using VBA code. I then protected the sheet and the protection blocks the VBA code search function.  Is there a way to add additional code to protect the sheet, but also still allow for filtering/search bar use? Below is the code that I used.  I am also very new to VBA code and Excel in general. Your input is greatly appreciated.
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("AllDepartments").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & Range("E1") & "*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="*" & Range("E1").Value & "*"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Thanks!

Have the code remove the protection the sheet, do the search then reapply the protection

Using argument AllowFiltering or UserInterfaceOnly.  Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.Protect method (Excel)


This question is similar to: Excel VBA - Filter data that is locked with password. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
